# Show dynamic external image in rdlc report table rows

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I want to show an external image in RDLC Report rows, the full image path saved in the database.

[This what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/473IQ.png)

I did the following steps, I changed the textbox properties as following:

Textbox Properties -> Background Image ->

- Source: External
- Value: =First(Fields!Image_URL.Value, "MyTable")
- MIMEType: image/jpeg

Then I added this line to my code:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
```

[The steps I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imcYb.png)

I still can not see any image in this text box, please advise me

Answer (score 0):

This is the example what I do. After insert image, go to image properties. Image source select External. Then, make you send correct URL to the dataset field.

[image]